# Como borrar datos de un datatable en java y con primefaces!

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

tengo un problema, como puedo borrar los regitros de un datatable al momento de dar en un botón de nuevo, lo que que a darle click al botón nuevo queda cargado el datatable:

Este es el botón para agregar uno nuevo:

```
public void actionNuevo() {
        flagIU = false;
        this.assignmentVO = null;
        this.routeVo=null;
        this.vehicleVOBo = null;
        customFieldsTrip = new ArrayList<>();

    }
```

Estes es el codigo del datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="tablas_tri"  scrollable="true" scrollWidth="100%" value="#{routeAssignmentBean.customFieldsTrip}" var="fieldTrpVO"  rowIndexVar="rowIndex">                                
                                    <p:column headerText="Tripulante1">
                                        <p:outputLabel value="#{fieldTrpVO.name_employee}" />
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="" style="max-width: 35px">
                                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" title="remove from cart"
                                                         accesskey="" process="@this" actionListener="#{routeAssignmentBean.deleteTripulante(fieldTrpVO)}"
                                                         update="tablas_tri" 
                                                         style="width:22px;height:22px;background-color:#FF0000;"/>
                                        <p:commandButton rendered="${beanVehicle.bottonEditarP}" class="btn-editar" value="" process="@this" title="Editar" actionListener="${routeAssignmentBean.selectCustomTripulante(fieldTrpVO)}" update="form_routes:nombreTripulante"/>               

                                    </p:column>
                                </p:dataTable>
```

Esta es la pantalla de lo que pasa cuando doy click en el botón:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Previamente se habia vuelto a dar click en el nuevo y no se borró, hay alguna forma de que ya no se muestre, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, saludos y quedo al pendiente.

Comment: Intenta aclarar un poco más tu pregunta. No me queda claro cómo es la secuencia de eventos que has probado, ni cuál ha sido el resultado ni tampoco cómo debería haber quedado

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que explicas, si es en la misma ventana, entonces das click al boton, y llamas un evento "nuevo", que inicialice tu datatable:
customFieldsTrip = new ArrayList<>(); y luego haces update="dataTableId".
Con este ya deberia quedar limpio el datatable.